# Uniformly Varied Rectilinear Motion (UVRM) (Animation)

Tags: java, swing

I'm making an UVRM calculator and also looking to make an animation of an image. I use the `Timer` class, for the animation, but it happens that I have problems in making the image stop when the **seconds** have passed or it has reached the entered **distance**, and of course it is done correctly.

`Timer`, it receives the **milliseconds**, and it occurred to me to pass the `seconds * 1000`, but I do not know if it is correct. Also, I need the image not to span the width of the window (JFrame)

I don't know much about animations and I don't know what to do really.

**Car class**

```
public class Car {

    private final ImageIcon imagen;
    private double posx;
    private int width;

    public Car() {
        imagen = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/carred.png"));
        posx = 10;
        width = 400;
    }

    public double getPosx() {
        return posx;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setPosx(double posx) {
        this.posx = posx;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(imagen.getImage(), (int) posx , 50, width, 300, null);
    }

    public void move(double x){
        posx+=x;
    }
}
```

**JPanel**

```
private void btnCalcActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    String text_vf = txfvf.getText();
    String text_v0 = txfv0.getText();
    String text_a = txfa.getText();
    String text_d = txfd.getText();
    String text_t = txft.getText();
    String res = "message.. res";

    // Calculations...        

    //text_d = distance
    moveCarImage(t, Integer.parseInt(text_v0), a, Integer.parseInt(text_d));
}           


private void moveCarImage(double timeMilis, double v0, double acceleration, int fDistance) {
    timer = new Timer(timeMilis, (e) -> {
        car.move(acceleration);
        repaint();

        if (car.getPosx() >= fDistance+car.getWidth() ) {
            timer.stop();
        }
    });

    timer.start();

    if (!timer.isRunning()) {
        System.out.println("Car Stopped.........");
    }
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    car.draw(g);
    
    //g.drawRect(10, 50, 300, 300);
}
```

Can you help me please.. thanks so much.

**EDIT:**

I changed the milliseconds a **timeMilis**

[image: image animation]

Comment: In your Timer, the first int is the number of milliseconds to wait.  You're multiplying your value * 1000, which will possibly lead to a long delay.  Could you create a [mre] and edit your question with the example that we can copy into our IDE, run, and debug?

Comment: I have modified what you suggested and added a demo. The car should move, but it stays in the same place.

Comment: [Edit] to add a [mre]. Either hot link to an image or (easier) create an image in code.

Comment: Already. I added more.

Comment: The timer moves the car (which updates the posx) then sets posx explicitly again, this seems redundant. Where is a set? is it potentially zero?

Comment: Sorry, I modified again and now the image does move, however it does not meet the set seconds and stops earlier. How could I position fix that and also make it not go out of the maximum width of the Frame?

Comment: *make it not go out of the maximum width of the Frame?* - check the location of the image relative to the size of the panel. You can't just use the "x" value. You also need to add in the width of the image.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Please help.